# Python/Ubuntu - Copy directory to new directory (incorrect directory path?)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, syntax

I'm trying to write my first Python script, and it is not going well.

I am trying to copy an entire local directory on my Ubuntu machine and place it and its contents in a different on my OS. I did some research and found `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src,dst)` should do just that.

This is the contents of my **backup_images.py** file:

```
import os
import sys

src = '/nodeGit/code/assets/images'
dst = '/usr/images_backup'

distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src,dst)
```

When I run it, I get error(s) on every line. When I run `./backup_images.py` in terminal, this is the output:

```
./backup_images.py: line 1: src: command not found
./backup_images.py: line 2: dst: command not found
./backup_images.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `src,dst'
./backup_images.py: line 4: `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src,dst)'
```

If I run the same command with sudo (`sudo ./backup_images.py`), I get completely different errors:

```
./backup_images.py: 1: ./backup_images.py: src: not found
./backup_images.py: 2: ./backup_images.py: dst: not found
./backup_images.py: 4: ./backup_images.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Based on the first couple errors of this, (`src: not found`,`dst: not found`), it seems Python isn't able to find the directories I assigned the  `src` and `dst` files to. Is this correct?

Because of the changing errors, I'm unsure of how to fix my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run .py file from putty, Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075561/unable-to-run-py-file-from-putty-syntax-error-word-unexpected-expecting)

Comment: Looks like you're executing the ``py`` script with the bash shell instead of the ``python`` binary.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to be the issue. Thanks. Now I'm getting an error, `name 'distutils' is not defined`, but I'd probably have to open a new Question for that if I'm unable to fix it/find an answer on my own, hm?...

Comment: You're not importing ``distutils``

Comment: `import distutils` wasn't sufficient to fix the error (nothing was imported into the directory on execute)...Am I missing something? I imagine I will want to use `distutils` in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `distutils` to do this. Instead use [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to perform a recursive copy of a directory and all its files and subdirectories.

```
import shutil

src = '/nodeGit/code/assets/images'
dst = '/usr/images_backup'

try:
    shutil.copytree(src,dst)
except shutil.Error as exc:
    # handle any exception that might occur
    print("Got exception {} while copying {} to {}".format(exc, src, dst))
```